# Recall Long Polling AJAX Request When it Fails/Network offline

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am implementing a successful **long polling** within PHP/Node.js application. I have created a routine to launch the long polling AJAX request after the waking up of the computer (after sleep mode) as below.

The problem is that the AJAX request fails due to internet connectivity as it needs some time to get ready and this leads AJAX request to fail. I need to recall this request again until the internet is back but I can't find any way to know if the previous request has failed to send new one and track its status.

I am not using the Jquery and I don't want to use it.

I am able to create a timeout for direct AJAX calls if they don't reach a server within a timeout seconds, but the long polling request status is pending at server for 40 seconds and I need to detect if it fails after 2 seconds from sending.

Is there any solution to do with xmlHTTP object?

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
var program ={
    init: function(){
        this.isSleep = function(lastTime){

            var lastTime = lastTime;

            clearTimeout(program.tt)
            program.tt = setTimeout(function(){

                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                if(currentTime > (lastTime + 2000*2) ){

                    // request fails if the internet connection was not ready  
                    ajax.call({ // long polling request......});
                }

                program.isSleep(new Date().getTime());


            }, 2000);
        };

        this.isSleep(new Date().getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: keep requesting normal request till you get a successful 200OK response. once you get it then start your long polling. you can use a flag for it.

Comment: I don't want to make a ping request before the long polling..

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to true, then call a timer for 2 seconds. If the ajax returns turn that variable to false, if the timer is fired then check your variable and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: In the case of long polling, the server doesn't respond before 40 seconds in my case.